# init wordpress svn repo in an existing wordpress directory

Tags: svn, wordpress, installation

I have an existing wordpress install that i'd like to upgrade using SVN rather than doing the in-app updates/traditional unzip and upload.

Is this possible??  Can i some how just init the svn repository right over the stuff i've currently got?

thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using svn export. The steps would be to SSH into your website, cd to the directory in which you would like the files to be in, then run the svn export command. It will be something like:

```
svn export svn://path-to-svn.com/trunk/
```

Make sure that what you have in your SVN is exactly what you want on your live server. One potential issue if you are not careful is that you can overwrite file within your wp-content folder. For instance, imagine that you add a new plugin via the live website. This will add files to the wp-content/plugins folder. If you perform your svn export, you will overwrite these files with whatever is in SVN. An alternative is that you can carefully and selectively export individual files and folders in order to avoid overwrite import files.

Source: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re10.html

Comment: sardine thank you so much for this!  One question... Based on what you said, i run a risk of overriding something in my wp-content folder.  If the svn repo has an empty directory, will it automatically empty out that folder locally?  For example... if i have content in /wp-content already and svn has wp-content as empty by default, does it automatically clear out the directory?

Comment: Because you would be exporting the site, yes, it would be overwritten even if the folder is empty. If you carefully orchestrated your workflow to make updates from your dev site, uploaded to your svn and then deploy via export, you would be mostly safe. You still might have some pictures or other attachments that could be in the uploads folder that could be overwritten.